# How to quickly add new language support for etags

Tags: regex, emacs, ctags, etag

I have a .ctags file with a language similar definition similar to that specified in the [ctags docs](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html):

```
  --langdef=swine
  --langmap=swine:.swn
  --regex-swine=/^def[ \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1/d,definition/
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with etags?  When building a new TAGS file I noticed (maybe for obvious reasons) my ~/.ctags file had no effect. I even tried copying ~/ctags to ~/.etags.  Likewise, I have come up dry for documentation on creating an .etags file.

Is this possible, am I missing steps, and does anyone know where I can find similar docs for etags (if it differs)?

**Edit: For the record my .ctags did exactly as I wanted, but I had to explicitly define "--regex=" when running etags for the same effect.**

Documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Etags-Regexps.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *possibly* running `ctags` ("Exuberant Ctags") from SourceForce, but the `etags` supplied with Emacs?

Try invoking `ctags -e` instead of `etags` ?

**Edit:** I am presuming that your .ctags config does actually take effect when you run `ctags`? You haven't explicitly stated whether that is the case, and if not then you may not actually be using the ctags that you think you are.

What do `ctags --version` and `etags --version` report?

Comment: ctags -e gave me a TAGS file that followed my .ctags guidelines.  This probably should have been a more obvious solution, thanks!

Comment: Also the versions were different as you suspected.  I don't suppose there's a way to define a .etags, for someone who is stubborn about running ctags to get their TAGS file?

Comment: My interpretation of the documentation is that the same config files will be processed regardless of whether you use ctags or etags mode, so it doesn't look like you can have a different .etags file. You could symlink .etags to .ctags, but there's not a lot of point in that. I can only suggest you either alias `etags` to `ctags -e [...]` (with all of the options you want to use for etags only) in your shell, or else create your own wrapper scripts to do similarly.

Comment: Yeah I was banking on etags honoring my .ctags file, but that didn't work in my case.  Aliasing etags to ctags -e works well enough.  Thanks.